# Authentication Cookie does not work in 3rd party Iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, samesite

I have a .net MVC 5 application.  The AuthCookie works fine with out the iframe and I can see the SameSite policy set to None.  However, in an iframe, the [Authorize] attribute method is stuck on a permanent redirect.  It appears that in the iframe the request can't read the cookie created by the code below.

I [followed the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite) and implemented [SameSiteCookieManager.cs](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetSameSiteSamples/blob/master/AspNet472CSharpMVC5/SameSiteCookieManager.cs)

**Web Config**

```
<httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None">
</sessionState>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

**Startup**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            { 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager()),
            CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
        });
```

**Account/Login**

```
 var user = UserManager.Find(userName,"*****");
 AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
 var identity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the browser.  Posting here just incase it will save some one else some time.
Turned out the issue was with my chrome incognito browser.  I had the "Block 3rd Party Cookies" option checked.[image]

Comment: this will soon be the Chrome default so we need a workaround